# Java Swing button actionEvent

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionevent

sorry to bother everyone.

Overall problem: I'm trying to open a dialogue box let the user enter something then close it

Issue: - A function is not being called (i think) 
       - The main problem is when i use debug it works fine so Its difficult for me to track down the problem

I'm having trouble with JButtons, 
it works in debug but not in normal run. this was probably because i was using an infinite loop. someone online suggested i used SwingUtilities but that didn't work (at least i don't think.

```
/**
 *
 * @author Deep_Net_Backup
 */
public class butonTest extends JFrame  {
String name;
boolean hasValue;

//name things
private JLabel m_nameLabel;
private JTextField m_name;

//panel
private JPanel pane;

//button
private JButton m_submit;

//action listener for the button submit
class submitListen implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        submit();
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

//constructor
public butonTest(){
    //normal values
    name = null;
    hasValue = false;
    //create the defauts
    m_nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
    m_name = new JTextField(25);
    pane = new JPanel();
    m_submit = new JButton("Submit");
    m_submit.addActionListener(new submitListen());
    //

    setTitle("Create Cat");
    setSize(300,200);
    setResizable(false);

    //add components
    pane.add(m_nameLabel);
    pane.add(m_name);

    pane.add(m_submit);

    add(pane);
    //last things
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

//submit
private void submit()
{
    System.out.println("submit");
    name = m_name.getText();
    hasValue = true;
}

//hasValue
public boolean hasValue()
{
    return(hasValue);

}

//get the text name
public String getName()
{
    return(name);
}

public void close()
{
    setVisible(false);
    dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    /* Test 1
    boolean run = true;
    String ret = new String();
    butonTest lol = new butonTest();

    while(run)
    {
        if(lol.hasValue())
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
            run = false;
            ret = new String(lol.getName());
            lol.close();
        }
    }



    System.out.println(ret);*/

    //Tset 2
    /*
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            butonTest lol = new butonTest();
            if(lol.hasValue())
            {
                System.out.println(lol.getName());
            }
        }
    });*/

}

}
```

Edit:
How its not working: When i run Test the program will print test and submit then it should change the hasValue to true. this will (hopefully) allow the if statement to run to print done. This does not happen.

Edit 2:
I have just added a few more lines for further testing 2 prints and this seems to have solved the issue (but this is bad)
System.out.println("hasValue " + hasValue); -> to the hasValue() function
System.out.println("set to true"); -> submit() function

Comment: How is it not working? Please give us the important details, and assume that we know nothing about your problem or code.

Comment: what are u trying to do? are you just trying to close the dialog?

Comment: Test1, your while loop is blocking the ui. Test2, your call to `hasValue()` only takes affect the _one_ time you call it, which is false

Comment: i'm trying to open a dialogue box get some user input return it then close it

Comment: Look at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). What you want is a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Thanks :D this looks like the answer (i must have missed it), sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something far too complicated than is necessary. Instead of having the listener as a seperate class, you could have it as an anonymous class. That way you can get a handle on the outer class (butonTest.this), and call any method you want on it.

```
m_submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        submit();
        System.out.println("Test");
        butonTest.this.close();
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the infinite loop. It would have run to completion before you show the dialog anyway.

It would help to read up a bit on how Event-Handling works in Swing :)

Comment: Thanks :D, I'll read up on them a bit more, i've been online and have looked through "Java how to program" but i guess i was more focused on the GUI rather then then going too in depth with Events

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your constructor butonTest() and submit() method are out of your
  class (public class butonTest extends JFrame).

you need to get them inside your class:

Comment: Sorry about that, i didn't space the last curly bracket properly